# How can I read SPI (Serial Peripheral Interface) data sent by a microcontroller on Windows

Tags: spi

I'm working with an Atmel ATMEGA328P microprocessor that is writing debug information out the MOSI SPI pin.  Is there a way to wire a connection to a Windows computer so I can see the debug information?

Ideally, there would be a breakout board or something that can be purchased that would allow me to run wires from the microcontroller's SPI ports to the board and then the board would have a USB connection so I can connect to my computer.  I've searched and nothing is coming up, but maybe I'm not using the right terms.

If a connection is possible, any references to code or an existing program for reading this data would really help.

By the way, the USART pins are already being used by the microcontroller for communicating with another device, otherwise I would've used them with a FT232R breakout board.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a poorly-disguised hardware shopping question.  I suggest the EE Stack Exchange as the proper place for discussing SPI interfacing.

Comment: google for: "spi pc adapter" and browse the hits. Alternative: Grab one of your spare microcontrollers, and do it yourself.

Comment: BTW other FTDI chips support SPI in addition to UART.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an SPI adapter. SparkFun has a cheap one for sale. If you have an Arduino or another Atmega328 lying around you can set it up as SPI host and use it as a SPI-USB adapter.

Comment: I didn't know an SPI adapter existed, but this sounds like this is what I'm looking for.  Thanks!